# Can anyone help me?

Tags: units

I was making a mesh for my project, then I scale the size smaller and apply the scale.

When I rotate the object, all the vertices seem to wiggle all over the place, then I try to add a sphere into the mesh, and the problem persists.

i post video of it here

https://youtu.be/7wHrCJtCDnM

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: That'a absolutely the worst title for a question ever. It doesn't convey any information about the question.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: well....i cannot agree ;) i saw titles like that in capital letters :D but i agree, the title is no help at all

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a precision issue. Blender uses 32bit floats for numbers describing coordinates. That's around 7 digits of precision. So you can have a number like 8562143 or 0.00005647895 but not 1.0000000001 - there is not enough precision for that. So if you have geometry too far away from the center of object's local space and/or scale it down too much this can happen.

That's Suzanne moved 20km away in it's object's local space and scaled down to 0.001 of its original size while scene units are set to meters:

[image]

She doesn't look too happy about it...

Make sure you don't have objects that contain geometry that has parts very far away or very different in size and are very far away from object's origin. Make those parts separate objects. You should also set your scene units adequately - if you work with micrometres and set your scene units to kilometres you will have precision issues for sure.